# Email provider which is fair by my standard and won't frequently grasped by bots as "spammy"

Tags: email-client

I need a recommendation for a browser based email client which is fair by my standard and won't frequently grasped by bots as "spammy".

## Necessary features

- Not owned by *Google, inc*, *Facebook, inc*, or *Apple, inc.*
- Gratis
- Has a reliable drafts mechanism
- Have a "contacts" list
- Allows total blocking of email addresses by *badlist* ("blacklist")

  - Emails from blocked addresses won't go to a SPAM folder or similar folder but would be automatically deleted (without a "trash" trace).
  - No manual setting up of a filter is required for blocking emails → emails from a badlist will just be deleted forever without me even knowing that they were sent
    (of course, the sender would have a copy of the sended email in its its outbox)

### Unnecessary yet preferable features

- FOSS
- Includes the folders *Inbox*, *Outbox*, *SPAM* and *Trash* and preferably not anything else (minimal environment)
- The email client program **will not** automatically add email addresses from which I got messages or sent message to, as "contacts" (or anything like that)
- If an email was deleted from all directories in which it appeared → neither its address, nor a browser cookie that are associated with it will remain so it will be gone forever
- Allows unsending emails up to at least 30 seconds

### Note

I actually used a similar email service a few years ago → [mail.com](https://mail.com), which with the company running it or anyone of their behalf I am not associated in any way besides using their service in the past but I stopped and moved to Gmail because:

When I used their service, a bot of the university I took some courses at at the time, recognized emails I sent from *mail.com* as spam and all went to SPAM folder of the recipients;
But, about seven years passed since I finished my studies and many changes happened in my mind and my life and I adopted a minimalist approach in regards to web applications and by that reduced the number of applications I used in about 75% by and I don't recognize why any similar problem should occur.

### My question

What email service will you recommend per the specification and details I have given?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 'grasped by bot as spammy'. Do you send spam? I would recommend https://protonmail.com or https://spamarrest.com.

Comment: @Chloe I don't send spam --- I meant that a bot of some email service might automatically recognize emails sent from my possible client as "spammy" although they aren't spam at all (perhaps a better term is "graded low in bots of other email clients").